# How do I allow www-data to (negatively) change the niceness of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, django, www-data, nice

So I'm running a website using django and sometimes I call scripts located on the server by spawning a subprocess in python.

When looking at the processes with "top" I see these are called under the user "www-data".

Because I want this server to act as a computation server **I want to be able to change the niceness of processes that are running, especially by giving them a higher priority (negative niceness).**

Unfortunately this only seems to be allowed by root. I've tried adding www-data to my sudoers file with ALL, and added it to both the sudo and admin group but none of these seem to work.

Also, I have another general question. If my process isn't maxing out the CPU will changing the niceness even do anything for it if I want to to be able to run "faster"?

Comment: If the CPU isn't capped, changing niceness will do extremely little to change the performance of the problem (like unnoticeable little)